# How to make a .bat to move files in a folder to a different folder, based on a text file listing the files to be moved?

Tags: list, batch-file, directory

I have a lot of files in one folder that I want to move to another folder. I have the files I want moved listed in a text file. Is there a way I can make a .bat so the files listed in the text file get moved to another folder?

I found this https://superuser.com/questions/355584/how-to-delete-files-from-a-folder-using-a-list-of-file-names-in-windows where this code

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (files_to_delete.txt) do del "%%f"
```

sort of does I want, meaning that the batch uses a text file to process files, except it deletes the files. How do I modify this code so the files are moved to another folder?

Another question, the above code deletes files without going through the recycling bin. So how do I modify the code so when it deletes, the files get moved to the recycling bin. If that happens, then I can easily drag it out to a new folder. I'm a newb using Windows 10. Thank you.

Comment: the [move](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) command does, what you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do I modify the code though? I'm a newb.                       'for /f "delims=" %%f in (files_to_delete.txt) do MOVE new "%%f"'                              new is the folder in the directory, does that work?

Comment: `MOVE "%%f" "c:\newfolder"` You can't use the recycle bin in batch (though you can in VBS by using shell objects). See `for /?`, `move /?`.

Comment: Thank you Noodles. `for /f "delims=" %%f in (list.txt) do MOVE "%%f" "c:\newfolder"   ` works. Thanks all.

Comment: Type `help` for a list of common command prompt commands and programs.